# Python matplotlib library install in max os x

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib library for Python. The installation was OK but I got the following error when I imported pylab (e.g. import pylab as p) in Python.

---

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 61, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Symbol not found: _png_set_longjmp_fn

  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so

  Expected in: flat namespace  in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
```

---

Google searches indicate that the link error (which does not look for "_png_set_longjmp_fn" ) is related to a 32/64 bit compiling issue for the png library.

I tried to re-install matplotlib based on README.osx file in the library but it was not fixed. Other methods that I found did not resolve it. Also, I checked out if the libraries are compiled at 32 or 64 bit. The relevant binaries support both ( universal binaries) as follows.

---

```
>file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so (for architecture i386):   Mach-O bundle i386

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64


>file /Library/Frameworks/libpng.framework/Versions/Current/libpng 

/Library/Frameworks/libpng.framework/Versions/Current/libpng: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures

/Library/Frameworks/libpng.framework/Versions/Current/libpng (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

/Library/Frameworks/libpng.framework/Versions/Current/libpng (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

---

My OS X version is Lion 10.7.4. Do you have any idea on this problem?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you might want to check out the [Enthought Python](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) distribution.  It contains matplotlib ready to go, plus other tools that are often tricky to install on OS X.

Comment: What did you do to install matplotlib? Did you compile from source? I suggest you install Enthought's python distribution like what @ChrisP says.

Comment: The enthought package fixed the problem. Thank you, Chris!  I got the matlablib from Github and compiled from the source code. Anyway, thank you, too, Jason!

Comment: Did you try the setup.py file instead of the make.osx? I have no problems with the former when using homebrew, and I was under the impression that it just works without homebrew too. In this case, it sounds like using enthought was the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue as yours the other day when I did from `matplotlib import pyplot` the other day. After five hours of slamming my head against the wall, this solution worked for me (from [practicalcomputing.org](http://practicalcomputing.org/node/69)

I got this set of commands to set up simlinks:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/freetype2/freetype /usr/local/include/freetype
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/ft2build.h /usr/local/include/ft2build.h
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/png.h /usr/local/include/png.h
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/pngconf.h /usr/local/include/pngconf.h
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/include/pnglibconf.h /usr/local/include/pnglibconf.h
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libpng.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib
```

It doesn't quite solve all your issues, but it solved my pkg-config issue (among others). Perhaps a similar link would help with QT.